# Select and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this select:

```
<form action="javascript">
<table width="100%">
<tr><td>Choose a map</td>
<td>
<select name="map" id="mapvalue" onChange="$('mapframe').src = $('mapvalue').value;">
<option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="Satellite views">
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/obs/sat/intl/ir_ICAO-B1_bw.jpg">Atlantic</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/obs/sat/intl/ir_ICAO-H_bw.jpg">North Atlantic</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/obs/sat/intl/ir_ICAO-G_bw.jpg">Europe / Asia</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/obs/sat/intl/ir_ICAO-C_bw.jpg">Europe / Africa</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/obs/sat/intl/ir_ICAO-E_bw.jpg">Indian Ocean</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/obs/sat/intl/ir_ICAO-A_bw.jpg">North / South America</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/obs/sat/intl/ir_ICAO-I_bw.jpg">North Pacific</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/obs/sat/intl/ir_ICAO-F_bw.jpg">South Pacific</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/obs/sat/intl/ir_ICAO-M_bw.jpg">Trans Atlantic</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="TEMSI Maps">
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2106.gif">Asia / Oceania</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2132.gif">Atlantic / North Pole</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2130.gif">Atlantic (Europe/Africa/America)</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2104.gif">Europe / Africa</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2107.gif">Europe / Asia</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2105.gif">Europe / Central Asia</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2108.gif">Europe / North America</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2101.gif">North America</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2133.gif">North Pacific</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2131.gif">Pacific</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2109.gif">South Africa / Australia</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2103.gif">South Atlantic</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2134.gif">South Pacific</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Color TEMSI Maps">
                    <option value="http://ows-public.sembach.af.mil/gifImages/21OWS_EUROPE_ANALYSIS_METSAT_00_SFC_METSAT-ANALYSIS-7.gif">Europe Current</option>
    <option value="http://ows-public.sembach.af.mil/gifImages/21OWS_EUROPE_FITL_PROG-BRIEFING_24.gif">Europe Forecast 24h</option>
    <option value="http://ows-public.sembach.af.mil/gifImages/21OWS_EUROPE_FITL_PROG-BRIEFING_48.gif">Europe Forecast 48h</option>
    <option value="http://ows-public.sembach.af.mil/gifImages/21OWS_EUROPE_FITL_PROG-BRIEFING_72.gif">Europe Forecast 72h</option>
    <option value="http://ows-public.sembach.af.mil/gifImages/21OWS_EUROPE_FITL_PROG-BRIEFING_96.gif">Europe Forecast 96h</option>
    <option value="http://ows-public.sembach.af.mil/gifImages/21OWS_EUROPE_FITL_PROG-BRIEFING_120.gif">Europe Forecast 120h</option>
                </optgroup>
<optgroup label="WINTEM Maps">
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2315.gif">Americas - FL100</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2311.gif">Americas - FL340</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2415.gif">Africa / Americas - FL100</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2411.gif">Africa / Americas - FL340</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2737.gif">Asia - FL100</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2733.gif">Asia - FL340</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2797.gif">Asia / Oceania - FL100</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2793.gif">Asia / Oceania - FL340</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2917.gif">Europe / Africa - FL100</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2913.gif">Europe / Africa - FL340</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2857.gif">Europe / Africa / Asia - FL100</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2853.gif">Europe / Africa / Asia - FL340</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2517.gif">North America / Europe - FL100</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2513.gif">North America / Europe - FL340</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2255.gif">Pacific - FL100</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2251.gif">Pacific - FL340</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2200.gif">North Pacific - FL100</option>
    <option value="http://aviationweather.gov/data/iffdp/2196.gif">North Pacific - FL340</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="CAT Forecast">
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN24a.GIF">Atlantic - 0h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN6a.GIF">Atlantic - 6h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN12a.GIF">Atlantic - 12h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN18a.GIF">Atlantic - 18h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN24.GIF">Pacific - 0h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN6.GIF">Pacific - 6h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN12.GIF">Pacific - 12h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN18.GIF">Pacific - 18h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN24p.GIF">Northern Hemisphere - 0h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN6p.GIF">Northern Hemisphere - 6h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN12p.GIF">Northern Hemisphere - 12h UTC</option>
    <option value="http://www.orbit.nesdis.noaa.gov/smcd/opdb/aviation/turb/tidaily/TIAVN18p.GIF">Northern Hemisphere - 18h UTC</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want that when you select an option the image loads for you without a page refresh. How Can I do that? What libraries I need??

Before that I was using prototypejs. And if you add it library it will work. But I need to use other library because I have problems with prototypejs.

Comment: Why are you using an `iframe` and not an `img` tag?

Comment: If I use img all will work??

Comment: Your jQuery selector `$('mapframe')` should be `$('#mapframe')` and `$('mapvalue')` should be `$('#mapvalue')`. Look at Tim Wasson answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is different from prototype.js in some ways. One of them is how you select an element with ID.

While this is how you select the element with 'mapframe' id in prototype.js:

```
$('mapframe')
```

this is how you do it in jquery:

`$('#mapframe')`

Comment: The code he gave is all the code needed to select an element with a given ID.

Answer (score 0):

change `onChange="$('mapframe').src = $('mapvalue').value;"`
to
`onChange="$('#mapframe').src = $('#mapvalue').val();"`

Answer (score 0):

I got this demo working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/b2yqt/

I used this jQuery:

```
$("#mapvalue").change(function() {
    $("#mapimg").attr("src",$(this).val());
});
```

and I removed the iframe and just put this:

```
<img src="" id="mapimg">
```